# Is it a bad practice to make request to 3rd party service to get token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, token, signing

Suppose this scenario:
I'm building service which works with user uploads to my AWS S3 account.
Each site using my service must have upload form which uploads directly to S3. In order to do that each site has to sign it's upload form with AWS Signature Version 4. 
The problem is signing requires AWSAccessKeyId and AWSSecretAccessKey which i must share to my service user and that's not acceptable.
I thought i can generate all needed signing data on my side and the just reply with that when user(site) asks for it.

So the question is: **is that a bad idea in order to sign upload form site(which is going to upload file to my S3) has to make request to my server for signing data(XHR or server side)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you're asking if it's a bad idea to sign the upload yourself on behalf of the individual sites, than the answer is no...with a caveat.

Signing the upload (really, you should just sign the upload URL) is far less of a security risk than providing other domains your access keys.  That's what it's there for, to allow anonymous uploads.  Signing the request merely gives the site/user permission to upload, but does not take into account who is uploading or what they are uploading.

This is where your own security checks need to come in.  If the form is hosted on multiple domains (all uploading to your S3 bucket), you should first check the domain the form originated from so as to avoid someone putting the form on their own webserver and trying to upload stuff.  Depending on how your various sites are configured, there are a couple of ways to do this, of which I am no expert unfortunately.

Secondly, you will want to validate the data being uploaded.  Is it pure text, binary, etc.?  You will want to validate all of that prior to initiating the upload.

I hope this helps.